# Is a secure client-side HTML5 canvas based Captcha possible?

Tags: encryption, canvas, obfuscation, client-side, captcha

A couple of days ago I toyed with the idea of creating an HTML5 Canvas based captcha to protect some form field input from robots.

The tricky part is that at some point you will have to call: `ctx.fillText(char, x, y);`

Basically the `char` variable coming from the server will be visible to the client unless using some sort of client side encryption.

Even still I think that the best you could achieve is some form of rotating obfuscation scheme so that automated robots would have trouble decrypting easily.

The reason I want the canvas client side is to keep server load down and reduce dependencies for the app (using node would like not to have to install Cairo for node-canvas etc...)

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Only for very small values of secure.

(In other words, no.)

There's no reason you'd want to other than bytes saved over the wire. Either way the server must spend the time to process a set of chars that its going to need to check. It might as well spend the time to make a base64 string to send to the client and use as the captcha.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was looking for more direction in the domain of server side encryption and client side decryption through the use of obfuscation or other methods.